# Add buttons to some cells in datagridView

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datagridview, custom-cell

Is there any way on C# WinForms to add buttons only in some of the cells so that they (buttons) were part of the cells? And add the handler for this buttons.
This need to that the values ​​for a particular cell inserted in another form. But it does not have to do all the cells in the table.
Like on picture.

[image: already added buttons]
<sub>(source: [snag.gy](http://i.snag.gy/vpD9Q.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Would it be *all cells in a given column*? If so, what does googling *buttoncolumn* give you?

Comment: If it were that easy...No, only in some cells.

Comment: Can't answer then. But +1 and will come back to read answers, if it can be done I want to know how!

Comment: That can easily be done in WPF.

Comment: I'm sure, but this is plain ol' WinForms. I think the answer involves some nasty p/invoke...

Comment: @retailcoder everything involves some nasty P/Invoke in winforms. It's an incomplete platform, therefore it needs to resort to external native windows features.

Comment: @streamdown I would seriously consider shifting to WPF, or using a 3rd-party grid control that wraps all the nastiness for you!

Comment: I've already started to think about it. It remains for me to check a couple of options.

Comment: @streamdown There's nothing to think about. There are basically 3 ways of doing anything useful in winforms: 1 - Buy DevExpress. 2 - Put an `ElementHost` in the `Form` and do everything in WPF, leaving winforms only as a container. 3 - forget winforms and use relevant non-obsolete technologies.

Comment: @HighCore Do you have any examples of how to implement a WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as an answer because the OP requested it:

This is my WPF take on that:

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.DataGridCustomCells"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MiscSamples"
        Title="DataGridCustomCells" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibiltyConverter"/>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="ButtonCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <!-- ControlTemplate obtained with Expression Blend -->
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <Button Height="16" Width="16" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        Visibility="{Binding (local:DataGridParameters.ShowButton), 
                                                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                             Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibiltyConverter}}"
                                        Command="{Binding CellButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding (local:DataGridParameters.ButtonValue), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>


    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonCell}">
                        <Setter Property="local:DataGridParameters.ShowButton" Value="{Binding DataContext.ShowButtonOnLastName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="local:DataGridParameters.ButtonValue" Value="{Binding DataContext.LastName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>    
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonCell}">
                        <Setter Property="local:DataGridParameters.ShowButton" Value="{Binding DataContext.ShowButtonOnFirstName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="local:DataGridParameters.ButtonValue" Value="{Binding DataContext.FirstName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class DataGridCustomCells : Window
    {
        public ICommand CellButtonCommand { get; set; }

        public DataGridCustomCells()
        {
            CellButtonCommand = new Command<object>(OnCellCommandExecuted){IsEnabled = true};

            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new List<DataGridSampleData>
                {
                    new DataGridSampleData() {LastName = "Simpson", FirstName = "Homer", ShowButtonOnFirstName = true},
                    new DataGridSampleData() {LastName = "Szyslak", FirstName = "Moe", ShowButtonOnLastName = true},
                    new DataGridSampleData() {LastName = "Gumble", FirstName = "Barney", ShowButtonOnFirstName = true},
                    new DataGridSampleData() {LastName = "Burns", FirstName = "Montgomery", ShowButtonOnLastName = true},
                };
        }

        private void OnCellCommandExecuted(object parameter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Command Executed: " + parameter);
        }
    }
```

Sample Data class:

```
public class DataGridSampleData //TODO: Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public bool ShowButtonOnFirstName { get; set; }

    public bool ShowButtonOnLastName { get; set; }
}
```

Helper Classes:

```
public static class DataGridParameters
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowButtonProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ShowButton", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridParameters));

    public static void SetShowButton(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ShowButtonProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetShowButton(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool) obj.GetValue(ShowButtonProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonValueProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ButtonValue", typeof(object), typeof(DataGridParameters));

    public static void SetButtonValue(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ButtonValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static object GetButtonValue(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.GetValue(ButtonValueProperty);
    }
}
```

Generic basic DelegateCommand:

```
    //Dead-simple implementation of ICommand
    //Serves as an abstraction of Actions performed by the user via interaction with the UI (for instance, Button Click)
    public class Command<T>: ICommand
    {
        public Action<T> Action { get; set; }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (Action != null && parameter is T)
                Action((T)parameter);
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return IsEnabled;
        }

        private bool _isEnabled;
        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get { return _isEnabled; }
            set
            {
                _isEnabled = value;
                if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                    CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public Command(Action<T> action)
        {
            Action = action;
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

- Notice That I'm using [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) to enable extra behavior in the existing `DataGridCell`s.
- Also, I'm using the [DelegateCommand](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) to have these buttons all redirected to the same underlying logic.
- There's not a single line of code in my example that deals with any UI element. All is done via DataBinding. That's how you code in WPF.
- This is a very basic and rudimentary example. You can create a much more scalable solution by defining a `RowViewModel<TEntity>` where each cell value is wrapped in a `CellViewModel<TValue>` that defines the button functionality and whether to show the button, and whatnot.
- No "owner draw", no P/Invoke, no horrible code-behind hacks.
- WPF Rocks. Just copy my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for expanded answer.